# Symfony/Doctrine: Select multiple tables

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

Im pretty new to Symfony and Doctrine and I can't find a solution to my problem.

I have a database table called `transactional` and one called `customer`. In the `transactional` table is a foreign key to the `customer` table. Now I want to get all the data from both tables. But the Customer fields are all set to null.

Here is the foreign key in the `transactional` php object:

`transactional`:

```
/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Customer
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Customer")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fk_customer", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $fkCustomer;
```

The Doctrine Query:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$transactions = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Transactional')->findAll();
dump($transactions);
```

The result:

```
0 => Transactional {#483 ▼
-id: 1
-date: DateTime @1510873200 {#493 ▶}
-fkCustomer: Customer {#566 ▼
  +__isInitialized__: false
  -id: 1
  -gender: null
  -firstname: null
```

Thank you very much for your time and help. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is doctrines lazy loading.

Once you access the customer property of your Transactional object the related information will be loaded.

This isn't ideal however if you iterate over many transactional entries since every customer object will be loaded through a single query.

You can solve this either by setting the fetchMode to `EAGER` like:

```
/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Customer
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Customer", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fk_customer", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $fkCustomer;
```

which should populate the customer data completely instead of using a proxy object.

Another way would be loading the transactional items through a custom repository method that explicitly joins the customer data. 
For example by creating a custom repository for `Transactional` and add a funciton like this:

```
public function load()
{
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('t, c')
        ->from('AppBundle:Transactional','t')
        ->join('t.fkCustomer', 'c');

    return $qb->getQuery()->execute();
}
```

how to create a custom repository can be found in the docs: https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/doctrine/repository.html

Comment: Thank you, I tried the first option so far, but it didn't work out. But I read now into the second one.

Comment: Hey, I haven't tried the second solution yet, but I came across something. In the Symfony debugging tool I found this query: `SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.date AS date_2, t0.fk_customer AS fk_customer_3 FROM transactional t0`. Shouldn't there be a join statement? Or is the join statement handled trough doctrine?

Comment: No if you are using the default repository functions like findAll doctrine queries only the table for this class. When fetch EAGER works it should join them yes, but i have also cases where the EAGER does pretty much nothing. I always use custom repositories in these cases because i can define the query which should be used and through the manual join actually achieve a single db query instead of many

Answer (score 1):

You have to set fetch type to eager:

**Eager Type:** Load the associated entity as well.

**Lazy Type:** Load the associated entity on need.

```
/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Customer
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Customer",fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fk_customer", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $fkCustomer;
```