# How do I get the data of the second entity via One-To-Many Bidirectional

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

I am confused right know and hope I get help here.
I am using 2 entities in symfony 3, which have got a **One-To-Many, Bidirectional** mapping.

**One User can have many adresses.**

User Entity:

```
class User extends BaseUser
    {


        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->address = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
            $this->created         = new \DateTime();
            $this->roles = array('ROLE_USER');

        }


        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * One Customers has many adresses
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Address",mappedBy="user")

         */
        private  $address;

     /**
         * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
         */
        public function getAddress()
        {
            return $this->address;
        }

        /**
         * @param Address $address
         * @return $this
         */
        public function setAddress(Address $address)
        {
            $this->address[] = $address;
            return $this;
        }
```

Adress Entity:

```
 * @ORM\Table(name="md_address")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\AddressRepository")
 */
 class Address
{

     public function __construct()
     {
         $this->created         = new \DateTime();
     }

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

     /**
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="address")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id",referencedColumnName="id")
      */
     protected  $user;
     /**
      * @var \DateTime
      * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime")
      */

public function getUser()
 {
     return $this->user;
 }


 public function setUser(User $user)
 {
     $this->user = $user;
     return $this;
 }
```

IN the Controller I call it:

```
$customer = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
        ->find($this->id);
```

The dump of

```
$customer ->getAddress()
```

shows

[image]

doctrine.yaml

```
orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        auto_generate_proxy_classes:  true
        proxy_dir:            '%kernel.cache_dir%/doctrine/orm/Proxies'
        proxy_namespace:      Proxies
        entity_managers:
              default:

                    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                    auto_mapping: true
                    metadata_cache_driver:
                               type: service
                               id: app.doctrine_orm.cache
                    result_cache_driver:
                               type: service
                               id: app.doctrine_orm.cache
                    query_cache_driver:
                               type: service
                               id: app.doctrine_orm.cache
                    second_level_cache:
                                enabled: true
#                    mappings:
#                        AppBundle:  ~
#                        FOSUserBundle: ~
#              mdtrack:
#                    connection: mdtrack
#                    mappings:
#                        AppBundle:  ~
```

**What do I have to do, that $customer-getAdress() shows all adresses, which are mapped to him. I just get the data schows in the dump ?**

The user field in adress maps to user. Those both entities are merged together after registration and adding a new adress later.

I think the form Types are not important for that problem here right know.

Comment: Side note: "address" in your user entity will return a collection so pluralize the identifier name to fit better code readability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if i understood your problem right but i think you are just confused because the address data is not shown in your object dump right after loading the user entity?

Have you tried calling `$customer->getAdress()`?

This might just be a doctrine lazy loading issue where relation data is loaded only if it's actually accessed. Until this happens the customer entity will only hold an empty proxy object.

```
$adresses = $customer->getAdress()
```

Edit: [Symfony/Doctrine: Select multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830646/symfony-doctrine-select-multiple-tables/47830835#47830835) for a more detailed answer

Comment: Yes, thats right, this is what I want. $customer->getAdress() shows the above dump

Comment: I think you misunderstand ... what you see in your "dump" above is the dump generated by the dump() - function in twig. That is hiding the data in case of doubt, especially if it's getting lazy loaded ... try to count the collection in php or twig with count($customer->getAdress()) in php or | lenght in twig ... if the count is the expected count, you are probably fine ... alternatively you can loop over your collection and dump the value for every item.

Comment: So now I unterstand it. I was looking for a problem where there was none. Thanks. It is working now